# a:before color in ie is not working

Tags: html, css, colors, html-lists

I've got a problem.
As you can see in my snippet I've got an accordion (which is usually working but in this case is not relevant). 
I give the a-tag :before with a color, which is working in every browser and even on every mobile device I've tested. 
Only in IE(11) and Edge it's not working that the :before is getting its color.

The color stays inherit. But I don't understand why. 
I hope somebody can tell me what I am missing. 
I've tried via !important set the color, but even that is not working :-(

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion-navigation .hc06_accordionLink:before {
  content: "";
  margin-top: 4px;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  color: red!important;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: none solid solid none;
  border-color: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
}

.accordion-navigation.active .hc06_accordionLink:before {
  margin-left: -15px;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.accordion-navigation:not(.active)>.hc06_accordionLink:before {
  margin-left: -20px;
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="hc06_accordion">
  <h3>Liste der unterstützten Geräte Subline #1</h3>
  <ul class="accordion" data-accordion>
    <li class="accordion-navigation">
      <a href="#faq01" class="hc06_accordionLink"> Laptop oder Computer</a>
      <div id="faq01" class="content">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis partuerient montesm nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
          quis, sem. <a href="phase2a_05.html"> Nulla con-sequat massa </a> quis enim. Donec pedo justo, fringilla vel.
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="accordion-navigation">
      <a href="#faq02" class="hc06_accordionLink"> Tablets und Smartphone</a>
      <div id="faq02" class="content">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis partuerient montesm nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
          quis, sem. Nulla con-sequat massa quis enim. Donec pedo justo, fringilla vel.
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="accordion-navigation">
      <a href="#faq03" class="hc06_accordionLink"> Spielekonsolen</a>
      <div id="faq03" class="content">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis partuerient montesm nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
          quis, sem. Nulla con-sequat massa quis enim. Donec pedo justo, fringilla vel.
        </p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: are you wanting `background-color`? Otherwise you need to put some text in `content` to see that as red

Comment: no, not the background-color, I want that the ">" red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `border-color: currentColor;`

This use current color for div, which is red here! It works in IE9+

Inherit have some issues here & different rules for different properties, using currentColor ensures that the color property value of active element is used!

Comment: THANKS! Oh my.. what a stupid error haha. I knew it was something little. Right now I'm feeling really stupid that I oversaw this one